# If $F$ is a field, show the following function is a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, permutations, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field. Show that the function $a\rightarrow a^{-1}$ is a permutation of $F\{0_F\}$

So I know that if it is indeed a permutation, then it is one-to-one and onto.

Also, For every $a$,$b$ element of $F\{0\}$, $a$ cannot equal $b$, and $a^{-1}$ cannot equal $b^{-1}$

So I think I need to assume that for every $b$ element of $F\{0\}$ there exists $a$ element of $F\{0\}$ s.t. $a^{-1}=b$.  Any insight on how to continue?

Comment: Do you have the field axiom $a \in F \ \text{and} \ a \neq 0 \implies \exists a^{-1} \in F$?  Does your version of this axiom say anything about uniqueness?

Comment: If a does not equal zero then a^-1 exists. Also, -a,a^-1 are unique @EricTowers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $ a\mapsto a^{-1}$ is its own inverse and so is a bijection.

Comment: so this was just using the definition then? Im just getting use to different math notations and am sometimes not sure what the question is fully asking.

Comment: A permutation is a bijection.  There is a theorem that states that the inverse of a function exists if and only if is it a bijection. For example, $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}  \ \ y= g(x) = 2x-1$. Prove that this is a bijection. Remember from hs math, just switch $y$ and $x$ and solve for $y$. i.e $x=2y-1 \rightarrow y= \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} = g^{-1}(x)$. To check this is the inverse, compose $g\circ g^{-1}(x) = 2(\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2})-1 = x +1 -1 = x $ You can try $g^{-1}\circ g(x)$. Since $g(x)$ has an inverse it is a bijection

Comment: If you let $\sigma(a) = a^{-1}$ be your function. Like @lhf said $\sigma^{-1}(a) = a^{-1}$ since $\sigma\sigma^{-1}(x) = \sigma(x^{-1}) = x$ and $\sigma^{-1}\sigma(x) = \sigma^{-1}(x^{-1}) = x$ . Since an inverse exist your function is a bijection/permutation.

Comment: @abe, thank you so much for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

By using  defination of field you can say that $F-\{0 \}$ is a group under multiplication, after that you can conclude $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an bijection as every element has uniqe inverse in a group.